# canvas RGBA to RGB conversion

Tags: javascript, performance, rgb, web-worker, typed-arrays

I have RGBA image from canvas and I use typedArray to remove alpha channel.

```
// data - arr from canvas. 

// [1,2,3,255, 1,2,3,255, 1,2,3,255,]
//  R G B  A   R G B  A   R G B  A

  const delta = 4;
  const length = data.length;
  const newLength = length - length / delta;

  const rgbArr = new Uint8Array(newLength);

  let j = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + delta) {
    rgbArr[j] = data[i]; // R
    rgbArr[j + 1] = data[i + 1]; // G
    rgbArr[j + 2] = data[i + 2]; // B
    j = j + 3;
  }
 
  // rgbArr [1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3]
```

I copy every 3 bytes to new Uint8Array. Can I do it in more optimized way without byte copying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your solution is pretty good. At least none of the alternatives I came up with so far comes anywhere close in performance. Run the snippet to see for yourself.

**Updated** with Justin's suggestion using `.filter` -- elegant but not faster.

```js
const data = new Uint8Array(1e8);

const delta = 4;
const length = data.length;
const newLength = length - length / delta;

const rgbArr = new Uint8Array(newLength);

let j = 0;

console.time('first');
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + delta) {
  rgbArr[j] = data[i]; // R
  rgbArr[j + 1] = data[i + 1]; // G
  rgbArr[j + 2] = data[i + 2]; // B
  j = j + 3;
}
console.timeEnd('first');

j = 0;
console.time('set');
const rgbArr2 = new Uint8Array(newLength);
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + delta) {
  rgbArr2.set(data.slice(i, i+2), j);
  j = j + 3;
}
console.timeEnd('set');

console.time('filter');
data.filter((el,i) => {
  return i % 4 !== 4 - 1
})
console.timeEnd('filter');

j = 0;
console.time('copyWithin');
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + delta) {
  data.copyWithin(j, i, i+2);
  j = j + 3;
}
console.timeEnd('copyWithin');
```

Results:

```
first: 102.900ms
set: 1185.700ms
filter: 2779.800ms
copyWithin: 415.100ms
```

Comment: thank you! Maybe is possible to use Uint32Array and bitwise operators for speed, like here https://jsfiddle.net/Fnx2w/467/  but I don't find way.

Comment: I stumped coz 4 bytes for array element in Uint32Array is always 4 bytes. Maybe possible to fill 4 byte  element as 3 bytes of current + 1 byte from  next element? And move bytes back, without zeroes between elements.

Comment: Yes, that's what the `copyWithin` solution does -- without cutting of the tail at the end, because it's too slow anyways.

Answer (score 1):

filter would be good here

```js
let array = new Uint8Array([1,2,3,255,1,2,3,255,1,2,3,255,1,2,3,255])

let filtered = array.filter((el,i) => {
  return i % 4 !== 4 - 1
})

console.log(filtered)
```